# sed replace with regex whole line

Tags: bash

There are two files:

`file1`:

```
dir='/root/path/to/somewhere/'
sed -zre "s|dir=(.*)'$|dir='$(echo $dir)'|g" -i file2
```

`file2`:

```
dir='/blah/blah/'
```

I want to do this:

> find a line having dir=(.*) and replace with the value of $dir

I run `bash file1`, but it doesn't replace anything in `file21.

Comment: Your `file1` is essentially a shell script. Add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line and `chmod +x file1` so you just just run it like `./file1`. .. It seems like your `sed` should work, but I have to leave to meet my wife. So I'm sure others will help. Good luck.

Comment: `$(echo $dir)` can be just `$dir`

Comment: @shellter it is a bash file and I think it has nothing to do with shebang. I run `bash file1` which is the same as yours. Have great night BTW.

Comment: @anubhava I tried but didn't change

Comment: Try: `sed -i "s|dir=.*|dir='$dir'|" file2`

Comment: this command will delete everything following the `dir` assignment, if that is not the final line in the input. Consider `seq 10 | sed -zre 's/5.*/also deletes 6 through 10/g'`. Contrast: `seq 10 | sed -zre 's/5[^\n]*/change one line/g'`. Also `/g` flag serves no purpose here.

Comment: @anubhava would you please write it as answer?

Comment: @jhnc what anubhava commented worked. Thanks for the comment and method.

Comment: The other problem is that `-z` changes the meaning of `$` - it no longer matches end of line

Comment: I found your original title confusing and wasn't sure if you understood you have a shell script in `file1`. Kudos for improving your question. Glad you have an answer! Good luck to all!

Comment: You're probably going to run into problems trying to use sed for that without escaping metachars, see [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed). FWIW I'd use awk instead since awk understands literal strings.

Comment: I don't see the point in using `echo`: Your string is within doule quotes, and the shell will expand `$dir` to the content of the variable. The _echo_ would just add a newline character and replace a run of spaces in the variable `dir` by a single space. A more serious problem is your _sed_  pattern. Since all 4 characters in _(.*)_ are interpreted as regex characters, you need to escape them if you want to treat them literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `sed` should work for you:

```bash
sed -i "s|dir=.*|dir='$dir'|" file2
```

Note removal of incorrect options `-zre` in this command and removal of redundant command substitution from your sed command.

Specifically problematic is use of `-z` that slurps complete input file in a single line of text thus failing to match `'$` since closing single quote is not the last character in file.

If you want to avoid repeating `dir=` 2 times then use a capture group:

```bash
sed -E -i.bak "s|(dir=).*|\1'$dir'|" file2
```